# Retorno com varios json com jquery .net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Preciso retornar para o ajax um json, ou melhor vários json, sendo cidade,bairro,estado,pais, cada um sendo um json no mesmo método, porem como não e possível fazer vários retorno coloquei as lista dos obj acima em uma lista de lista.

```
        List < List<String> > final = new List < List<String> >();
        final.Add(cidade);
        final.Add(bairro);
        final.Add(estado);
        final.Add(pais);
```

logo abaixo retorno o json da lista final

```
        return Json(final, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

porem quando vou exibir os dados no ajax, quando acesso a posição dados[1] ou 2 ..., ele pega como uma lista inteira e não como um json, acho que ele retornou o json so as posições  0,1,2... e não o que tem dentro dela, como fazer para retornar esses dados como json

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
     cidade.change(function () {
        $(function () {
            $('#loading').html('<img  
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
                url: "GetDados",
                data: { Cidade: cidade.val() },
                success: function (dados) 
                $(dados).each(function (i) {
                   alert(dados[1]);
                    });
                 }
            });
        });
    });
})

</script>
```

Comment: Tem como mostrar o java scrip que está usando para visualizar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

controller:

```
var result = new { cidade, bairro, estado, pais };
return Json (result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

"result" é um [objeto anônimo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397696.aspx)

javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
     cidade.change(function () {
        $(function () {
        $('#loading').html('<img  
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            url: "GetDados",
            data: { Cidade: cidade.val() },
            success: function (dados) {
               alert(dados.cidade);
             }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```